# how to get the date as NSDate with format yyyy/mm/dd using nsdateformatter

Tags: nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *newformat = [NSDateFormatter new];

[newformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *string = [newformat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

i am getting string as required format but not date i tried following one

```
NSDate *newone = [secondformatter dateFromString:string];
```

Comment: data formatter's format should be same. Else it will return nil.

Comment: what date format have you given to `secondformatter`?

Comment: here is the second formatter
NSDateFormatter *secondformatter =[NSDateFormatter new];
    [secondformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH-mm-ss"];

But its giving me the date as 2013-05-02 16:00:00 but i want as 2013/05/02

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
   NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];
    NSString * dateEndPrev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY a"];

    NSDate *tmp = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateEndPrev];
    NSString *strNew = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:tmp];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormat1 dateFromString:strNew];
```

It may work for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I want the output as NSDate which contains the date as "yyyy/MM/dd" your solution giving me the date as yyyy-dd-MM do u have other thoughts to get as yyyy/MM/dd

Comment: i have given my required format but its giving me 2013-05-02 any other  ways to get nsdate as 2013/05/02

Comment: okay i got you what you want... Its default of nadate. You just get it in NSString format not over Date.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting string in the required format it means formatting is done successfully. Your code should work without any problem. So what are you doing to check if formatting is done? Printing a date object prints the date in default UTC format without any formatting. So checking dates by printing it wont work.

This may help you in checking, or so the documents say, ie printing the output of formatter directly but i wouldnt bet on it...

```
NSLog(@"%@", [secondformatter dateFromString:string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDate doesnt have a format.It comes in a single format.The formatter makes the string in specific format for you from the date object.There also the date remains the same.

```
 NSDateFormatter * dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];//here the output string will be in the fromat specified here
NSString * dateEndPrev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateEndPrev);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research , i understand that its not possible to hold the date with "yyyy/MM/dd" this format in NSDate like NSCalendarDate.

Comment: That something isn't possible is still an answer :-)